# What is the difference b/w @RequestParam and @QueryParam Anotation

Tags: spring-mvc

What is main difference between `@RequestParam` and `@QueryParam` in Spring MVC controller?

Comment: They're functionally the same: they let you bind the value of a named HTTP param to the annotated variable. That being said, the question is very broad, so you'll have to specify more detail if you want a more useful answer.

Comment: my question is regarding their use in spring mvc controller...      So please describe briefly...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Apart from these mentioned differences in framework, one major difference is `@RequestParam` will always expect a value to bind. Hence, if value is not passed, it will give error. This is not the case in `@QueryParam`

To explicitly give the option, use required = false while using `@RequestParam`

Comment: Also that `@RequestParam` is Spring Framework specific and needs no extra dependencies, except web related of course. Whereas, `@QueryParam` is under RESTful API for Web Service, hence has dependency of jsr311-api.

Answer (score 60):

`@QueryParam` is a [JAX-RS](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-queryparam-example/) framework annotation and `@RequestParam` is from [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

Comment: Please also specify which(out of both) one i have to use when in spring mvc model controller

Comment: QueryParam is from another framework and you are mentioning Spring. @Flao wrote that `@RequestParam` is from Spring and that should be used in Spring MVC.

Comment: but i saw many Spring MVC Controller Example in which we use both(@QueryParam and @RequestParam annotation) type of annotation. That is why my question is that which one should be used when...

Comment: Could you please provide links to them?

Answer (score 21):

I'll try to shed some more detailed light on this question.

Let's start with semantics of **Query Parameter** vs. **Request Parameter**, respectively `@QueryParam` vs. `@RequestParam`

**Query Parameter**, according to the HTTP Specification and also according to this annotation's (`@QueryParam`) implementation `JAX-RS`, represents the parameter found in query string. i.e. the string which follows the question-mark in the full request URL.

**Request Parameter**, according to the HTTP Specification and also according to this annotation's (`@RequestParam`) implementation `Spring MVC (org.springframework.web.bind.annotation)`, represents the parameter of HTTP request, and to be clear here, it doesn't specify which type of parameter it is - query, header, body or etc.

---

Now let's talk about implementations per se.

### @QueryParam

`@QueryParam` annotation belongs to `JAX-RS` specification, which [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html), that:

> @QueryParam Binds the value(s) of a HTTP query parameter to a resource
>   method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean
>   property

Pay attention here, it's **query parameter** which is bound to resource method's parameter (i.e. parameter in query string)

### @RequestParam

`@RequestParam` on the other hand, belongs to Spring Framework, which [states](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html), that:

> @RequestParam annotation indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter.
>   • In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form data, and parts in multipart requests. This is because the Servlet API combines query parameters and form data into a single map called "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of the request body.

---

Therefore, I think the names may be indeed a little bit misleading, but after digging in a little bit more, they are quite self-explanatory. Just try to stick with one when you want only query parameter and with another when you want any request parameter.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above another difference I observed is QueryParam do not translate parameters values to List type however RequestParam does.

What I mean is "@RequestParam("para") List param" is able to convert comma separated param values to List, @QueryParam fails to translate this.