# What is the difference between @PathParam and @PathVariable

Tags: spring-mvc, jax-rs, restful-url, path-parameter

To my knowledge both serves the same purpose. Except the fact that `@PathVariable` is from Spring MVC and `@PathParam` is from JAX-RS. Any insights on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)

Comment: Suresh, i like your own answer better than the answers below. I think perhaps it's important to note that 1) Spring honors PathParam as well as its own PathVariable, and 2) whenever possible Java's PathParam is preferrable (because you may replace Spring some day with another technology, but as long as you are working with Java...)

Comment: Expecting answers regarding cases on when to to use path variable and when to use path parameter.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[@PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) and [@PathParam](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) both are used for accessing parameters from [URI Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_Template)

Differences:

- As you mention `@PathVariable` is from spring and `@PathParam` is from [JAX-RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services).
- `@PathParam` can use with REST only, where `@PathVariable` used in Spring so it works in MVC and REST.

See also:
[Difference between @RequestParam and @QueryParam Anotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55721061/1697099)

Answer (score 44):

**QueryParam:**

To assign URI parameter values to method arguments. In Spring, it is `@RequestParam`.

Eg.,

```
http://localhost:8080/books?isbn=1234

@GetMapping("/books/")
    public Book getBookDetails(@RequestParam("isbn") String isbn) {
```

**PathParam:**

To assign URI placeholder values to method arguments. In Spring, it is `@PathVariable`.

Eg.,

```
http://localhost:8080/books/1234

@GetMapping("/books/{isbn}")
    public Book getBook(@PathVariable("isbn") String isbn) {
```

Comment: Is it not request param in your first example

Comment: Your PathParam heading is misleading because the explanation you have given is of @RequestParam (not PathParam)

Comment: @Omkar Your explanation is wrong !!!
PathParam is javax.ws.rs which is equivalent to Spring's PathVariable.
Similarly, QueryParam from javax.ws.rs is equivalent to RequestParam

Comment: @ImamBux - thanks for noticing it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 12):

**@PathParam** is a parameter annotation which allows you to map variable URI path fragments into your method call.

```
@Path("/library")
public class Library {

   @GET
   @Path("/book/{isbn}")
   public String getBook(@PathParam("isbn") String id) {
      // search my database and get a string representation and return it
   }
}
```

for more details : [JBoss DOCS](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/_PathParam.html)

In Spring MVC you can use the **@PathVariable** annotation on a method argument to bind it to the value of a URI template variable
for more details : [SPRING DOCS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html)

Comment: in other words, it does the same, but `@PathVariable` is the equivalent to be used in Spring (?)

Answer (score 1):

`@PathParam` is a parameter annotation which allows you to map variable URI path fragments into your method call.

`@PathVariable` is to obtain some placeholder from the URI (Spring call it an URI Template)

Answer (score 0):

Some can use @PathParam in Spring as well but value will be null when URL request is being made 
Same time if We use @PathVarriable then if value is not being passed then application will throw error

Answer (score -2):

**@PathVariable**

@PathVariable it is the annotation, that is used in the URI for the incoming request.

http://localhost:8080/restcalls/101?id=10&name=xyz

**@RequestParam**

@RequestParam annotation used for accessing the query parameter values from the request.

```
public String getRestCalls(
@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) int id,
@RequestParam(value="name", required=true) String name){...}
```

Note

whatever we are requesting with rest call i.e, @PathVariable

whatever we are accessing for writing queries i.e, @RequestParam

Comment: though my question is difference between pathvariable and pathparam. Thank you for the reply .

Answer (score -2):

***@PathParam***:  it is used to inject the value of named URI path parameters that were defined in **@Path** expression.

Ex:

```
@GET
@Path("/{make}/{model}/{year}")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public Jpeg getPicture(@PathParam("make") String make, @PathParam("model") PathSegment car, @PathParam("year") String year) {
        String carColor = car.getMatrixParameters().getFirst("color");

}
```

***@Pathvariable***: This annotation is used to handle template variables in the request URI mapping ,and used them as method parameters.

Ex:

```
     @GetMapping("/{id}")
     public ResponseEntity<Patient> getByIdPatient(@PathVariable Integer id) {
          Patient obj =  service.getById(id);
          return new ResponseEntity<Patient>(obj,HttpStatus.OK);
     }
```