# are these pathParams or pathVariable

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have to write an API call

```
@GET
@Path("/{settingName1, settingName2}")
public Response getNetworkSettingValue(@ApiParam(value = "Name") @QueryParam("name") String name,
        @ApiParam(value = "City") @QueryParam("city") String city,
        @ApiParam(value = "State") @QueryParam("state") String state) {}
```

here my doubt is how to get `settingName1 & settingName2` values, 
can write like

`@ApiParam(value = "SettingName1") @PathParam("settingName1") String settingName1`

or

`@ApiParam(value = "SettingName1") @PathVariable("settingName1") String settingName1`

in method declaration.

or

any other way to get those two values

Comment: You could use both but I'd stick to the @PathParam. See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367501/what-is-the-difference-between-pathparam-and-pathvariable

Comment: Let me know if my answer was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

By the [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation, I assume you are using JAX-RS (Jersey, RESTEasy, etc). So it should be:

```java
@ApiParam(value = "SettingName1") @PathParam("settingName1") String settingName1
```

If you were using Spring, it should be:

```java
@ApiParam(value = "SettingName1") @PathVariable("settingName1") String settingName1
```

Answer (score 0):

your annotations are mixed up with spring and swagger.

If u want to accesss pathvariables with spring than it have to be like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{settingName1}/{settingName2}", method = equestMethod.GET)
public Response getNetworkSettingValue(@ApiParam(value = "settingName1") @PathVariable final String settingName1,
                                       @ApiParam(value = "settingName2") @PathVariable final String settingName2) {
...
     return new Response();
}
```