# Why Use PathVariable instead of PathParam?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

Before marking this as duplicate, just wanted you guys to know I have checked out the question posted here: 
[What is the difference between @PathParam and @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367501/what-is-the-difference-between-pathparam-and-pathvariable)

Thing is, if the usage of PathParam and PathVariable are same (only that one is from the JAX-RS API and one is provided by Spring), why is it that using one gives me null and the other gives me the proper value?

I am using Postman to invoke the service as:
http://localhost:8080/topic/2

(I'm very new to SpringBoot)

Using PathParam :

```
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.json.ParseException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TopicController {

    @Autowired
    TopicService topicService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,path="/topic/{id}")
    public Topic getById(@PathParam("id") long id) throws ParseException {
        return topicService.getTopicById(id);  //-- here id comes as null (when id is declared as a wrapper type - Long, else it throws an error)
    }
}
```

Using PathVariable:

```
@RestController
public class TopicController {

    @Autowired
    TopicService topicService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,path="/topic/{id}")
    public Topic getById(@PathVariable("id") long id) throws ParseException {
        return topicService.getTopicById(id);  //-- here id comes as 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the pathparam in your project is under javax.ws... This one is not what they talked about. It is used in websocket, which means it is not a http annotaiton. JBoss implement pathparam needs additional jars.

Comment: The one that I have imported is : import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;