# File missing in spring boot when receiving form data sent by ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

I need to send a html form to a springboot application. The Form is manipulated before submitting, so I use an ajax request to submit it manually:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: form_submit_url,
    data: formData
});
```

I checked formData to be sure that it contains all form values including files.

The following code works for all form items except files. Inspecting *functionRequest* shows that file parameters are missing.

```
@PostMapping(
    value = "form_submit_url",
    consumes = {
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
    },
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public FunctionResult executeFunction(
    final @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, Object> functionRequest
) {
    return null;
}
```

MultiValueMap is used since received parameters may vary.

Is it possible to reiceive files along with other parameters when using MultiValueMap? Otherwise is there an alternative?

Comment: you should not use @RequestParam if your controller catches POST requests, as POST requests sends data in a body payload

Comment: Please check this link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457382/can-i-use-requestparam-annotation-for-a-post-request

Comment: I already tried to use @RequestBody but it results in an error: "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryiABkW6WBEvdbrXZZ;charset=UTF-8' not supported".

Your link suggests to create a DTO, but that's not possible since I don't know the parameters.