# parameters as request parameters on POST method

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, post

This question is about best practice and not about problem.

I am writing a `spring boot` rest service that will perform update meaning basically i am doing `POST`operation. The input parameters are something like `userId`,`name`,`emailAddress`,`phoneNo`.

So my question is, can i do something like below. Just use `POST` to tell this is update `uri` but pass all parameters as request param instead of `requestBody`

```
@PostMapping(value="/my-url )
    public ResponseEntity<?> myMethod(
          @RequestParam(value = "userId")  String userId,
          @RequestParam(value = "name")  String name,
          @RequestParam(value = "emailAddress")  String emailAddress,
          @RequestParam(value = "phoneNo")  String phoneNo){
```

I know this works but, is this acceptable ? **If this is okay , what is the purpose of using request type as `POST` if we are passing parameters in the form of requestparam.** 
Expert view is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Instead of passing lot of parameters, you can create a request body either in xml or json format to increase the visibility.

Comment: isn't it fundametally wrong to use requestparam with `POST` ?

Comment: Technically you can do it but it is always used as request body in case of post request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use @Requestparam annotation for a Post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457382/can-i-use-requestparam-annotation-for-a-post-request)

Comment: not a duplicate. I am asking best practice and that question is different.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using parameters (or form parameters in the body) in a POST request. That has been the way the web has been working since its inception, so no there is nothing wrong with it. Although you probably want to create a model (`User`) and automatically let Spring bind the parameters for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Speaking of the best practice i belive the best way is to create a model that will be a `@RequestBody` paremeter better then pass a number of parameters in the `url`. moreover, creating a model you denenitlly guarantee a fixed bunch of possible parameters, plus you don't need care of their mandatoriness anymore.
BTW. the best practice for an update action is a `PUT`, but not `POST` request

Comment: Thanks for `PUT` and `POST` clarification. So you are saying don't do it but better try not to. So what is the purpose of setting request type as `POST` if we are passing everything as requestparam ?

Comment: sorry, didn't thoroughly get your question( anyway. answering your own question in comments: yes, it's completely wrong to use `POST` for update - there are international agreements. 
Speaking of a parameters passing.. well nobody forbids you do as you wan, but it depends on an app requirements. Where is a guarantee that the next week won't appear a requirement to update a more complicated model? in this case the best way is to make a fundament for a scalability

Comment: you are saying use requestbody but you are not saying don't use requestparam. Am i right ?

Comment: yap. generally you shoud separate parameters that are responseble for "addressing" of the request and parameters that will be updated. Imagine you need to update a book's publish date and it's ISBN , so the parameters that will be updated are a "isbn" and "publish_date" and them you shoud add into the input model, and the key for update is an id of the book. So then you can make smth like that: `@PutMapping(value = "api/book/{bookId}" public ResponseEntity<?> myMethod(
      @RequestBody UpdateBookModel model, @PathVariable("bookId") Long bookId {...}`

Comment: Additional remarks: You can use `PUT` or `PATCH` for an update action, but `PATCH` is often to make changes to part of the resource.