# Adding SuppressWarnings to Spring controller generate 404 not found

Tags: spring-boot, api, spring-restcontroller, suppress-warnings

I'm using Spring boot to expose an API.

For the method `createTransaction` in `TransactionController`,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/Transactions")
public class TransactionController{

@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<Transaction> createTransaction(
        @RequestParam Optional<String> name) {
    // stuff
}
}
```

The API works perfectly, but I have the following warning :

> Warning:(29, 27) 'Optional' used as type for parameter 'name'

When I add a `SuppressWarnings` to avoid the compilator warning for this specefic method when I use `Optional` as a parameter (since I'm aware of the risk)

> @SuppressWarnings("OptionalUsedAsFieldOrParameterType")

The API return `404 not found`

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-06-05T11:32:36.053+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/Transactions/create"
}
```

Any idea on what's the issue ?
I want to use `Optional` parameter without getting warnings.

Comment: Using `@RequestParam` with a `POST` request should be avoided. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457597/3266467

Comment: @Sebastian Noted, but is it somehow related to my issue ?