# Spring Boot 405 POST method not supported but GET method works

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot with Spring MVC to do a simple CRUD User Registration HTML5 form with a number of fields to post using the POST submit method. I have a REST Controller which uses @Controller and @ResponseBody, which goes through a user service that calls methods to handle the GET, POST calls to the repository using Spring's JPA repository. As soon as the user keys in a new user record and hits the submit button, the controller will save the record and transfer to the listAllUsers.html view (which contains a grid to show all saved users) using Spring's Model and View.

The user record is succesfully saved when I both use the GET AND POST methods as the action methods in the submitting form and the controller method but after that, the GET method successfully directs my view to listAllUsers.html but the POST method doesn't. When I use the POST method, I get a "Spring Boot 405 POST method not supported" and I am not directed by the controller to the view listAllUsers.html. How do I get redirected to the view, listAllUsers.html using the POST method? I reproduce my code below.

registerNewUser.html:

```
<div class="card" style="">
  <div class="container" style="padding:30px;">
    <span style="font-size:20pt;">用户注册</span><br/><br/>
    <form id= "add_user" name="add_user" method="POST" action="/addUser">
    <div class="card-body">
    <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" width="50%">
    <tr><td>昵称</td><td><input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" style="" size="20" placeholder="单行输入"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>电话号码</td><td><input type="text" id="txtTelNo" name="txtTelNo" style="" size="20" placeholder="单行输入"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>密码</td><td><input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" style="" size="20" placeholder=""></td></tr>
    <tr><td>邮箱</td><td><input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" style="" size="20" placeholder="单行输入"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="height:20px;"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" style="width:60%;text-align:center;" value="注册"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
    
     
  </div>
</div>
```

UserController.java:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserService service;


/*@PostMapping(
            value = "/addUser",
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUser(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("txtUserName") String usrName, @RequestParam("txtTelNo") String telNo, @RequestParam("txtPassword") String password, @RequestParam("txtEmail") String email,
    HttpSession session) {

        User savedUser = new User();
        
        savedUser.setUserName(usrName);
        savedUser.setUserTelNo(telNo);
        savedUser.setUserPassword(password);
        savedUser.setUserEmail(email);
        savedUser.setUserRole("开发 人员");
        
        service.addNewUser(savedUser);
        
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("listUsers");

        return mav;
    }    
}
```

I got this error message in my console:

```
2021-01-24 23:51:12.604[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m17700[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-7][0;39m [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

This error message was shown on the white page :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator.checkRequest(WebContentGenerator.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:536)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: This post might help you to solve problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457382/can-i-use-requestparam-annotation-for-a-post-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally got it working with the POST method. I just added a "redirect:" to the return parameters of the controller to redirect to the required views and of course changed to the POST methods for the calling form and the controller. Here is my modified code below:

```
    //login
    @RequestMapping(value= "/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestParam("txtUserName") String usrName, @RequestParam("txtPassword") String password) {
        
        System.out.println("LOGIN UserName : " + usrName + " Password : " + password);
        
        //Process the admin password - hardcoded
        if(usrName.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin123")) 
            
            { return "redirect:main.html"; }
        
        else 
            
            { return "redirect:invalid_login.html"; }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing @RequestBody and @RequestParam.
Your controller method needs a RequestBody object and not String parameters.

Comment: I've used RequestParams for @RequestMapping using the POST method before without any problems.