# Spring Boot array of JSON strings as a param of x-www-form-urlencoded request content

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

As far as I know, Spring Boot has two ways of passing arrays in request parameters:

1. comma separated values, ex: `numbers=1,2,3,4,5`
2. repeated parameter name, ex: `numbers=1&numbers=2&numbers=3&numbers=4&numbers=5`

In my example below, it first tries to convert an array using method 1. then after exception it successfully convert it using method 2.

---

### My questions are:

is there any way to tell Spring Boot to use only method 2.?

Alternatively is there any way to escape commas in JSON string passed as request parameter of `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type?

---

DemoObject.class:

```
public class DemoObject {
    
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Integer count;

    //Constructor, Getters and Setters

}
```

DemoController.class:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    
    @PostMapping("test")
    String test(@RequestParam List<DemoObject> objects, @RequestParam Integer number) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return "["+number +"] " +om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(objects);
    }
    
}
```

DemoConverter.class:

```
@Component
public class DemoConverter implements GenericConverter {

    private final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    
    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        Set<ConvertiblePair> convertibles = new HashSet<>();
        convertibles.add(new ConvertiblePair(String.class, DemoObject.class));
        return convertibles;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object o, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        try {
            return om.readValue((String) o, targetType.getType());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DemoConverter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new RuntimeException("Conversion failed");
        }
    }

}
```

---

Sample request 1.:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/test  
Body x-www-form-urlencoded  
objects:{"name":"test","description":"AAA"}
number:123
```

Spring Boot throws an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: 
Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object 
(start marker at [Source: (String)"{"name":"test""; line: 1, column: 1])
```

But result is correct with status 200 code.

---

Sample request 2.:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/test  
Body x-www-form-urlencoded  
objects:{"name":"test","description":"AAA"}  
objects:{"name":"test2","description":"BBB"}  
number:123
```

No exception, status 200, correct result.

---

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi mateusz-kowalski, so the RequestParam it is when you pass them in the URL like in the examples you did, but your actually request it is a POST sending in the body. So first thing, it is RequestBody the annotation you need for the Controller. Also, you don't need the converter. If you just send "[ {"name":"test","description":"AAA"} ]" it will be mapped as array to the controller with [ ] to show JSON that it is a array .

Comment: @Brother I updated example with another arg. I want to pass multiple args. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457597/5970359 - here is smillar thread, about passing request params in POST, but any of them are not satisfactioning me. If i should not use RequestParam in POST, so what is proper annotation or method to do so without creating any data wraper or dealing with maps.

Comment: Also i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980438/5970359 it seems that RequestParam with body of x-www-form-urlencoded is allowed.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html