# sending List<String> in rest api request but receiving wrongly

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, rest

My code is as below from where I am calling REST API

```
 List<String> a =  [b]
MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestParam = new LinkedValueMap<>();
requestParam.add('a', a);
restTemplate.postForObject(URL, requestparam,String.class);
```

On receiving end code is as

```
ResponseEntity<Object> functionName(
@Requestparam(value='a', required=true) List<String> a
){
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
Sysout(a.get(i));
}


}
```

It print as ["b"]
and in query parameter used as ["b"] while it should be as b

Comment: is your request is of type `curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/so/2987755?a=b,c,d' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'`?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your question

1. '' is characters in java and "" is String
2. There is no mention of request type GET/POST, inferred this from `postForObject`
3. If you are using POST call then instead of passing arguments as RequestParam, you can pass it as BodyParam as mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457597/2987755), but still, RequestParam can be used with POST call.

**Solution 1: Considering POST call with `@RequestBody`**

*Controller:*

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/so/2987755", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ResponseEntity<List<String>> functionName(@RequestBody List<String> a){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(a.get(i));
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(a, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

*Client:*

```java
List<String> a = Collections.singletonList("b");
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a), headers);
return restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/so/2987755", request,String.class);
```

**Solution 2: POST call with `@RequestParam`**

*Controller:*

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/so/2987755", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ResponseEntity<List<String>> functionName(@RequestParam(value = "a") List<String> a){
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(a.get(i));
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(a, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

*Client 1:*

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


Map<String, String> requestParam = new HashMap<>();
final String requestParamKey = "a";
requestParam.put(requestParamKey, "b,c,d");
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
return restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/so/2987755?a={" + requestParamKey + "}", request, String.class, requestParam);
```

*Client 2: Another flavor of Client using `UriComponentsBuilder`*

```java
MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParam = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
final String requestParamKey = "a";
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("b", "c", "d");
requestParam.put(requestParamKey, a);

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://localhost:8080/so/2987755");
builder.queryParams(requestParam);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

return restTemplate.postForObject(builder.build().encode().toUri(), request, String.class);
```

This both client call prints at the controller

```
b
c
d
```

The reason RequestParam is printed as ["b"] because you are using `List<String>` in `LinkedValueMap` instead if you use just `MultiValueMap<String, String>`, things will work as you expected.
What you observed is while deserializing List it will become `["b"]` but if you use `UriComponentsBuilder` you will not face such issues.