# Spring Boot/Kotlin ignore value field of @QueryParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jax-rs

I have a Spring Boot/Kotlin web application and a controller that takes a query param.

Here's my controller method:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam
...
@GetMapping("/items")
@ResponseBody
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
fun getItems(@QueryParam("n") count: Int? = null): Collection<MyItem>  {
    return myItemService.list(count)
}
```

The following cURL results in a null `count` parameter:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/items?n=25
```

Instead, Spring Boot always uses the variable name as the query param value:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/items?count=25
```

What gives? Is this a bug in Spring Boot, or did the Spring team intentionally ignore the documentation on how `@QueryParam` should work and choose to favor variable name over annotation value?

Comment: you should use `@RequestParam` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709560/what-is-the-difference-b-w-requestparam-and-queryparam-anotation

Comment: That's helpful but still leaves me curious why the creators of Spring Boot mis-implemented the JAX-RS specification.

Comment: Spring MVC is the actual name of the Spring web framework and is _not_ a JAX-RS implementation. And Spring Boot is Spring's bootstrapping framework to make launching applications simpler. So what you are using is Spring Boot to launch a Spring MVC application. Just some FYIs.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha sure, but why support JAX-RS annotations at all if Spring is going to do it incorrectly? Honestly feels like a bug in Spring, and I'm curious if there's any justification for it.

Comment: _"but why support JAX-RS annotations at all"_ - It doesn't. Which JAX-RS annotations do you think Spring MVC support? The two frameworks are completely different and have no relation at all.

Comment: On further examination, @PaulSamsotha is right: Spring ignores all JAX-RS annotations. I had thought that Spring was responding to `javax.ws.rs.Produces` and `javax.ws.rs.QueryParam`, but on further examination, I found that in both cases I mistook Spring's defaults for it responding to JAX-RS annotations. Specifically, Spring defaults to `Content-Type: application/json` and maps un-annotated method params by name to query params. Carry on.